# Dart mixin with a polymer observable field possible?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

So lets say I have a mixin class defined like so:

```
abstract class TestMix
{
  @observable bool loggedIn = false;

  updateLogin(){
    if (isLoggedIn()){
      loggedIn = true;
    }else{
      loggedIn = false;
    }
  }
}
```

I'd want to mix in this behavior to a few polymer views, so I do:

```
@CustomTag('my-app')
class App extends PolymerElement with TestMix {

  App.created() : super.created() {
    this.updateLogin(); // @observable field 'loggedIn' is changed in the mixin
  }
}
```

I get no binding joy.  If I move the mixin fields/methods directly into the App class, then everything works fine and binding occurs.

Just want to confirm if this is possible or not?  Can Dart reflect on mixin fields just like native fields?  Or if there is a way to manually cause the binding pass to occur (would prefer not).

Comment: This should work, can you file a bug? Also you might try implementing Observable on TestMix.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can.  I have found this way works

```dart
abstract class TestMix implements Observable
{
  bool _loggedIn = false;

  @reflectable bool get loggedIn => _loggedIn;
  @reflectable set loggedIn(val) {
    _loggedIn = notifyPropertyChange(#loggedIn, _loggedIn, val);
  }

  updateLogin(){
    if (isLoggedIn()){
      loggedIn = true;
    }else{
      loggedIn = false;
    }
  }

  isLoggedIn() => true;
}
```

Using

```dart
@observable
```

in the mixin causes real trouble where it keeps saying mixin needs to extend Object, even when you do.  So I had to take a look at the docs in the source code and came across that suggestion in the above code, or something similar. Look in the observe package under observe/observe.dart.  Though the trouble

```dart
@observable
```

caused in the mixin may just be a bug.

Oh and don't forget, to minimise the size of the generated code, as suggested by the docs, use

```dart
import 'package:observe/mirrors_used.dart';
```

when using things annotated with

```dart
@reflectable
```

Though I'm not totally sure Polymer apps need this import